# Always show DocumentTabStrip on DockPanel

Tags: c#, .net, dockpanel-suite

The behavior that's causing me a problem is when the user splits `DockPanel` with multiple `DockContent` documents. If the user then wishes to move or close the `DockContent` on the new panel section is no way to do so. To me the most userfriendly approach would be to show the Tabs all the time, even if there is only one object on the panel section. Is this possible? If not does anyone have another solution?

Here is what I am talking about. As you can see on the right there is no way to move or close that control and unsplit the Panel
[image: No tab available to close or drag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of DockingSdi DocumentStyle.  DockingMdi or DockingWindow should be used for the desired behavior.

A more complete answer can be found on the reposted question: https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/154